# How understand interpolation about box-shadow described on MDN?

Tags: css, box-shadow

Happy new year!

When I was reading the description of CSS property box-shadow, I can not figure out what Interpolation section on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) means.
I googled for this but still confused.
Is it about CSS animation?
Could you please help? Thanks.

Please provide some code examples if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me have a stab at digesting this block of nonesense

> Each shadow in the list (treating none as a 0-length list) is
>   interpolated via the color (as color) component, and x, y, blur, and
>   (when appropriate) spread (as length) components.

Each shadow in the list is interpolated (various meanings but generally: mixed, blended) using the color, x, y, blur and spread values.

> For each shadow, if both input shadows are or are not inset, then the
>   interpolated shadow must match the input shadows in that regard. If
>   any pair of input shadows has one inset and the other not inset, the
>   entire shadow list is uninterpolable.

We can only interpolate (blend, mix whatever) the same type of shadow, be it inset or not, we cannot blend an inset shadow with a non inset shadow

> If the lists of shadows have different lengths, then the shorter list
>   is padded at the end with shadows whose color is transparent, all
>   lengths are 0, and whose inset (or not) matches the longer list.

I'm not sure how you would end up with a list of various lengths but from what I can garner this is saying that if we somehow end up with a list of different lengths, the browser will compensate for this by adding in transparent shadows so that it has something to interpolate (blend, mix etc) with

TL;DR

It's just explaining the steps that the browser goes through to interpolate multiple shadows and isn't related to animations from what I can see.
Don't worry about it, let the browser do it's thing!

Comment: Much more clear. Thanks. I thought it would be related with animation because I had learnt interpolation means inserting frames between two key frames. For the last part, list**s** having different lengths, it maybe refer to more than one box-shadow lists. For example, `box-shadow: 3px 3px red` and `box-shadow: 3px 3px blue, 0 0 1em black`. But why would a list interpolate with another list? The later rule should override the precedent one, right?

Comment: @krave Honestly that bit stumps me too, I can't figure how you would end up with a list of different sizes being that you're applying one list of shadows! I just can't figure that bit out :)

Comment: @krave And in regards to your version of interpolate.. it is the same whether you are blending animations with new frames or blending shadows together or even swapping out words in a sentence they can all be considered interpolation... my first introduction to interpolation was through music creation software where you could automate things using interpolation :)

Comment: Interpolation everywhere... You are right. Leave it to the browser unless implementing a browser myself which is out of my range. Many thanks :)